# SQL: Select Count Of Instances Up To Each Current Instance For Each Category In Column Ordered By Date

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table including dates and a discrete category column (username).
I'd like to get the number of times each user has showed up in the table, but added as a column to the table.
The result would indicate how many times that user has showed up in the table up to the date in the date column.

For example:

```
Id      Date      Username
        ------    --------
6age        1/3/23     User1
8s9a        1/3/23     User1
d29j        1/3/23     User2
fj48        1/2/23     User1
39k9        1/2/23     User3
a8j3        1/1/23     User1
0ao2        1/1/23     User1
ajd6        1/1/23     User1
am50        1/1/23     User2
amv8        1/1/23     User3
```

Desired output:

```
Id        Date      Username    Instance
        ------    --------    --------
6age        1/3/23     User1       6
8s9a        1/3/23     User1       5
d29j        1/3/23     User2       2
fj48        1/2/23     User1       4
39k9        1/2/23     User3       2
a8j3        1/1/23     User1       3
0ao2        1/1/23     User1       2
ajd6        1/1/23     User1       1
am50        1/1/23     User2       1
amv8        1/1/23     User3       1
```

I am working with SQLite. The database has 22 million rows, so I am trying to find an optimized approach. Sadly, the ID is not numeric. Though, I know I can overcome that with row_number().

Comment: I'm afraid that without a primary key it will be difficult to accomplish your goal. Are you sure your Date column isn't a timestamp with unique values ?

Comment: there is only row_number, and you want all rows, you could try an Index that is corectly sorted

Comment: @StefanoLosi You're right, it is a timestamp column, but it contains duplicates. It wasn't meant for use as PK. I do, however, have a primary key column which I failed to include. I've updated the question. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A working solution would feature two steps:

- update the schema of your table with the new field
- update matching unique ids, while using a computed row-number (partitioning on users, ordering on dates and ids)

```
ALTER TABLE tab ADD COLUMN Instance INT;

UPDATE tab
SET Instance = cte.rn
FROM (SELECT id, 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Username ORDER BY Date, id DESC) AS rn
      FROM tab) cte
WHERE tab.id = cte.id;
```

**Output**:

| Id | Date | Username | Instance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6age | 1/3/23 | User1 | 6 |
| 8s9a | 1/3/23 | User1 | 5 |
| d29j | 1/3/23 | User2 | 2 |
| fj48 | 1/2/23 | User1 | 4 |
| 39k9 | 1/2/23 | User3 | 2 |
| a8j3 | 1/1/23 | User1 | 2 |
| 0ao2 | 1/1/23 | User1 | 3 |
| ajd6 | 1/1/23 | User1 | 1 |
| am50 | 1/1/23 | User2 | 1 |
| amv8 | 1/1/23 | User3 | 1 |

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aseJkcLo3zFLs373Qk7tzx/4).